# Should Threads be avoided if at all possible inside software components?

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns, f#, components

I have recently been looking at code, specifically component oriented code that uses threads internally. Is this a bad practise. The code I looked at was from an F# example that showed the use of event based programming techniques. I can not post the code in case of copyright infringements, but it does spin up a thread of its own. Is this regarded as bad practise or is it feasible that code not written by yourself has full control of thread creation. I do point out that this code is not a visual component and is very much "built from scratch".

What are the best practises of component creation where threading would be helpful?

I am completely language agnostic on this, the f# example could have been in c# or python.

I am concerned about the lack of control over the components run time and hogging of resources, the example just implemented another thread, but as far as I can see there is nothing stopping this type of design from spawning as many threads as it wishes, well to the limit of what your program allows.

I did think of methods such as object injecting and so fourth, but threads are weird as they are from a component perspective pure "action" as opposed to "model, state, declarations"

any help would be great.

Comment: What's your definition of "component"? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I use component to mean a glob of software that's intended to be used, without change, by application that is out of the control of the writers of the component. By 'without change' I mean that the using application doesn't change the source code of the components, although they may alter the component's behavior by extending it in ways allowed by the component writers ----Martin Fowler

Comment: Making 'globs of software' thread-safe is a considerable effort.  The author will surely not fail to point this out several times in the docs.  If that is missing, you can safely assume it is *not* thread-safe.

Comment: If you're worried about starving the system, consider using `ThreadPool`. There is only one pool per process and it scales nicely.

Comment: using ThreadPool makes it available to all, including component writers, It may take over the ThreadPool and starve other areas of your system where you expect x number of Threads in the pool to be available. After thinking about this, I think its all about transparency, more than fear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is too general a question to bear any answer more specific than "it depends" :-)

There are cases when using internal threads within a component is completely valid, and there are cases when not. This has to be decided on a case by case basis. Overall, though, since threads do make the code much more difficult to test and maintain, and increase the chances of subtle, hard to find bugs, they should be used with caution, only when there is a really decisive reason to use them.

An example to the legitimate use of threads is a *worker thread*, where a component handling an event starts an action which takes a long time to execute (such as a lengthy computation, a web request, or extensive file I/O), and spawns a separate thread to do the job, so that the control can be immediately returned to the interface to handle further user input. Without the worker thread, the UI would be totally unresponsive for a long time, which usually makes users angry.

Another example is a lengthy calculation/process which lends itself well to parallel execution, i.e. it consists of many smaller independent tasks of more or less similar size. If there are strong performance requirements, it does indeed make sense to execute the individual tasks in a concurrent fashion using a pool of worker threads. Many languages provide high level support for such designs.

Note that components are generally free to allocate and use any other kinds of resources too and thus wreak havoc in countless other ways - are you ever worried about a component eating up all memory, exhausting the available file handles, reserving ports etc.? Many of these can cause much more trouble globally within a system than spawning extra threads.

Comment: Yes I take your point to the question being too general. But the question was very general in its nature. Was after some sort of guidelines. The trouble I see is that without being able/want to "look inside" a component, or have any control over a component, should the component have that much control over thread execution.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong about creating new threads in a component/library. The only thing wrong would be if it didn't give the consumer of the API/component a way to synchronize whenever necessary.

Comment: I believe what Lawrence meant is either make these threads transparent to component consumer or provide an info about how to use the component safely regarding multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is the nature of component you are talking about? Is it a dll to be consumed by some different code? What does it do? What are the business requirements? All these are essential to determine if you do need to worry about parallelism or not.

Second of all, threading is just a tool to acheive better performance, responsivness so avoiding it at all cost everywhere does not sound like a smart approach - threading is certainly vital for some business needs.

Third of all, when comparing threading symantics in c# vs f#, you have to remember that those are very different beasts in theirselfs - f# implicitly makes threading safer to code as there is no notion of global variables hence the critical section in your code is something easier to eschew in f# than in c#. That puts your as a deleloper in a better place bc you dont have to deal with memoryblocks, locks, semaphores etc.

I would say if your 'component' relies heavily on threading you might want to consider using either the parallel FX in c# or even go with f# since it kind of approaches working with processer time slicing and parallelism in more elegant way (IMHO).

And last but not least, when you say about hogging up computer resources by using threading in your component - please remember that coding threads do not necessarily impose higher resource impact per se – you can just as easily do the same damage on one thread if you don’t dispose of your objects (unmaneged) properly, granted you might get OutOfMemeory Exception faster when you make the same mistake on several threads…

Comment: Its all much of a muchness. C#, F#, <place your language of choice here>, all do pretty much the same. There is always a flow of execution, and all commands whether imperative or declarative have a flow of execution. Comparing F# to C# and saying one is better than the other is just wrong. They are the same thing under the hood. Threading is not a tool, threading is about the control of the execution. Who said anything about Parallelism? Threads control asynchronous call backs too :)

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers: They are not "the same thing under the hood".